# Missing,android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

I have copied code from https://www.javatpoint.com/android-google-map-displaying-current-location

Here permission request already provided
But I am getting above error, can someone please explain

Comment: Did you declare the permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I have declared it in manifest